# How to get control back after drawing on scene

Tags: c++, qt, graphics

I am trying to implement simple backtracking algorythm (solitaire game) and I also want to show the progress, not only the answer. So I decided to use QGraphicsView to draw gamefield's status on it. I want to update scene after I field's changd and when I want to get control back, to resume changing gamefield. What is the best way to do this?

UPD:

pseudocode

```
List<Step>* solve(GameField& field) {

    //changing gamefield, clearing scene, adding some objects (rects with text) to scene
    updateScene(); //here I want the scene to be updated right now, and
                   //not when it's scheduled to
}
```

Comment: You're thinking too synchronous ;). Even if that would be possible, it would be too fast to see the single steps. Use a QTimer to trigger the next step.

Comment: What do you want to show? Is it an animation, text or something else? Please show some code.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld that's exactly what I want to see - there would be thousands of steps, so ofcourse I want them to pass quickly.

Comment: You must return to the event loop for painting to happen. If you want it to proceed more quickly, choose a smaller timer interval.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld and how do I get control back after returning to event loop and paintin in it?

Comment: By an event being triggered, e.g. a QTimer timeout.

Comment: You can call `QGraphicsView::repaint` to repaint the view immediately.